# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'myproject.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have an almost fresh install of django and when I try to python manage.py runserver.It is is giving me this error:

```py
 File "C:\Users\..\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 50, in ge
t_internal_wsgi_application
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'myproject.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'cognitive.apps.CognitiveConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'jchart',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

what could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: have you installed all of the required modules ?

Comment: yes I have already installed the required modules

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently, but it was because I was reconfiguring my settings for a more complex project. I looked up the `WSGI_APPLICATION` in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#wsgi-application), and it seems the default setting for this is `None`. So I commented the line out in my settings file and the local development server worked again with `./manage.py runserver`.

Then I read the documentation more clearly and it states that this is "[t]he full Python path of the WSGI application object that Django’s built-in servers (e.g. **`runserver`**) will use." When this setting is `None`, Django will call `django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application` as a fallback. Perhaps you should try the above to see what happens. Might give a clue to your issue.

Another thing to try is using `django-admin runserver`. This takes the `manage.py` (which sets `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`) out of the equation and might give you some additional clues.